Why does running a Python program from the Command Line requires me to type the path in quotes?
Screenshot
They are exactly the same down to the path, it's just that the one with quotes worked and printed "Hello world!" while the one without gave me an error message instead. When I watch videos of other programmers doing this, they don't type the quotes and it works for them. Now I'm just wondering if those videos were just outdated and the Command Line does require quotes now...?

Does your user name have a space in it?

It looks like there might be a space character (or other delimiter/escape character) in your user name. Path with spaces should be surrounded by double quotes ("").
Python uses the Windows C runtime to parse the command line into an argument array (available inside Python as sys.argv).
You could use ctypes, to see the difference between the two cases for yourself. Add -i to your python command (to get REPL afterwards), and type:
>>> import ctypes
>>> kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
>>> shell32 = ctypes.WinDLL('shell32', use_last_error=True)
>>> kernel32.GetCommandLineW.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
>>> shell32.CommandLineToArgvW.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)

>>> cmd = kernel32.GetCommandLineW() # get command as is
>>> num = ctypes.c_int()
>>> args = shell32.CommandLineToArgvW(cmd, ctypes.byref(num))  # parse it

>>> print(*zip(range(num.value), args[:num.value]), sep='\n')

The debugging code is from https://bugs.python.org/issue42499 (by @eryksun).

If your python script path contains spaces or special characters, you need to enclose the path in quotes to ensure that the command line interprets it correctly. Otherwise the command line might interpret the space as a separator between different paths.
For example, if your script is located at C:\My Python Scripts\helloworld.py, running it without quotes might lead to an error because the Command Line will interpret it as two separate arguments: 'C:\My' and 'Python Scripts\helloworld.py'.
Therefore it is best to enclose you script path in quotes.
If the path doesn't contain any spaces or special characters, you might not need to use quotes. But it is beneficial to use them because if you are using the script across platforms then the file path may vary and cause issues due to spaces or special characters.
Hope it helps...!
